# map in SML tycon mismatch

Tags: types, functional-programming, sml

I am trying to make a function that maps strings of the form `"SXSXSSSXXX"` to `instruction list`s `[S,X,S,X,S,S,S,X,X,X]` where

```
datatype instruction = S | X
type sequence = instruction list
```

I am using `map` and `String.explode : string -> char list` to achieve this:

```
fun str_to_sequence(s: string) =
    map(fn c => if c = #"S" then S else X, String.explode(s))
```

The first argument to map is of type `char -> instruction`, and the second argument is of type `char list`. This matches the type signature of `map :  ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list`, where `'a = char`, `'b = instruction`, however, when I try to compile this, I get the following tycon mismatch:

```
- use "stack_sequences.sml";
[opening stack_sequences.sml]
[autoloading]
[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/basis.cm is stable]
[autoloading done]
stack_sequences.sml:5.5-5.62 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
operator domain: 'Z -> 'Y
operand:         (char -> instruction) * char list
in expression:
map ((fn c => if <exp> then <exp> else <exp>),String.explode s)

uncaught exception Error
raised at: ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:66.19-66.27
../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:44.55
../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:296.17-296.20
```

What is wrong with the code? I can't find a type mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error report says map's operator domain is

```
'Z -> 'Y
```

but your operand is

```
(char -> instruction) * char list
```

So, you are giving map a tuple instead of a function.

`map` is implemented in a curried form.

Your code should be

```
map (fn c => if c = #"S" then S else X) (String.explode s)
```

Comment: I see, I was mistaking `map` for a 2-ary function, it's a unary function that returns a unary function. Thank you!

Comment: @Doug: It should actually be `map (fn c => ...) (explode s)`. I.e., if you don't add parentheses around the expression `explode s`, then `map (fn c => ...)` will be applied to the function `explode`. This is because function application is left-associative and binds very tight. (Assuming here that `map` = `List.map` and `explode` = `String.explode`.)

Comment: Thanks, Simon. I'll fix the answer.